# Add tems to array with keys in PHP

Tags: php

How to add array items to an existing array with key => value ? actually i want to create an array of mysql rowset i.e.

```
$n =0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowset))
{
   $array[$n] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'city' = $row['city']);
   $n += 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: to combine two arrays you may want to check array_merge() function http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
$existingArray['newKey'] = 'new value';
```

Or use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) function:

```
$newArray = array_merge($existingArray, $additionalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

That what you're looking for?

-edit-

Just to note, if conflicting results are found, the last most array entry will be used. If you  array merge three arrays with id fields, only the final arrays id will be stored in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into this:

http://php.net/array_push

Should be simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

For One:

```
$array['key'] = $value;
```

Merge:

```
$mergedArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)